# How can i play different music playlists through different output sources on the same media player?

Tags: music, media-player, audio-streaming, playlists, audio-output

How can I play different music playlists through different output sources on the same media player?

So one Bluetooth speaker playing nirvana. Headphones playing Led Zeppelin. And network speaker playing AC/DC. All on the same media player at the same time. What combination of solutions can I do that with? So for example, if I were to use Media Player Classic how could I change their output sources on a per-instance basis? Or do I need a multiple software solution using Virtual Audio Cable somehow?

Comment: Does it have to be the same player? Or to be more precise, does it have to be the same instance of it? AFAIK you can only set the output per-application(-instance) but you could run multiple instances of the same media player (e.g. using `su -` to run as different users) and then set different output streams using `pavucontrol`.

Comment: @confetti it could be multiple instances, but even then I’m not sure how to change the output source setting for a media player to different things for different instances.

Comment: What OS are you using or how to us? Please note that requests to recommend software are off topic. You could rephrase this question to remove the parts about requesting a software package to do this and instead ask how this can be accomplished.

Comment: @music2myear I’m doing this with Windows 10

Comment: Oh I thought we're talking Linux. On Windows, no idea.

Comment: @music2myear Should I keep waiting for a solution to this using multiple software in combination like multiple media player instances with virtual audio cable or something, or should I just repost this on Software Recommendations?

Comment: They are two different questions, maybe. If you're looking for software, then close this question because that's off topic here. If you're asking HOW to play multiple streams  from one audio player to multiple discrete targets, that question could be posed here as it would be on topic. What you do depends on what you want.

Comment: @music2myear well what if I want both?

Comment: I'm sorry it hasn't been more clear to you yet: Asking for software recommendations is OFF TOPIC on SuperUser, and is ON TOPIC on the Software Recommendations SE site. If you want both then I thought I made it clear enough when I stated that you have two different questions. Please respect the rules of the sites. Doing so is more likely to result in satisfaction for you, and less likely to result in frustration for those who may have an answer (or two) for you.

Comment: @music2myear ok I’ll modify the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use VLC Media player, you can change the audio output device on a per-instance basis.

All you have to do is open `Audio` -> `Audio Device` Then you can select the speaker that you want to play it out of.

More generally spoken, you need a media player, that supports

- running more than one instance at a time (probably in the same user session)
- setting the audio output device on a per-instance basis (like VLC does)

Comment: I tried it and it turns out I can do the same thing with Media Player Classic too. I'll accept this answer, but don't go getting a big head or anything. XD